# explode() on Japanese string

Tags: php, string, delimiter

I have to use the explode() function on Japanese text but it doesn't work.

Here is an example of what I have

```
$string = '私　は　イタリア　人　です';
$string = explode(" ", $string);
print_r($string);
```

That prints

```
Array ( [0] => 私　は　イタリア　人　です )
```

in place of

```
Array ( [0] => 私　[1] => は　[2] => イタリア　[3] => 人　[4] => です )
```

It seems that `explode()` can't recognize the spaces inside that text.

What's the reason? How could I make it work?

Comment: Why is there a space between "イタリア" and "人"?

Comment: I know that イタリア and 人 should be put together, but I need to take them as separated entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is for the simple reason that you do not have a space character here.
You have an "IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE" character  with the hex code "e3 80 80".

If you use that as your delimiter, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong space. The text uses full-width spaces (U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE) and you're supplying a half-width space (U+0020 SPACE).

Answer (score 3):

There're two issues here.

First of all, you don't say what your encoding is but I suppose all Japanese encodings are multi-byte. On the other side, the [`explode()` function](http://php.net/explode) (like all regular PHP functions) expects single-byte input. There's no exact multi-byte equivalent but [mb_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) could do the trick.

Secondly, you are exploding by regular space ([U+0020](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm)) but your string contains another character ([U+3000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm)).

To sum up (and assuming you are using UTF-8):

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

$string = '私　は　イタリア　人　です';
print_r(mb_split('　', $string));
```

... or even better:

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

$string = '私　は　イタリア　人　です';
print_r(mb_split('[[:space:]]', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your string first using `iconv()` and then use it on explode. Convert to utf8

```
$string = explode(" ", iconv('', 'utf-8', $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of characters other than simple ASCII space that can add whitespace between characters.

You could try using preg_split using \s (whitespace characters) or \b (word boundaries) as the pattern, however this may not be ideal as Japanese is almost certainly going to be encoded in a multiple-byte format.